# unit testing asp.net routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit

is there a way to test routes via nunit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rippo's examples are good.  I am using MVCContrib's TestHelper library.

It makes testing the route a breeze and is very easy to setup/use in nunit.

The test is extremely easy to construct and understand:

```
"~/".ShouldMapTo<HomeController>(x => x.Index());  

"~/recipe".ShouldMapTo<RecipeController>(x => x.List());
```

I have a [blog post](http://www.kevinlabranche.com/blog/TestingASPNetMVCRoutesWithMVCContribsTestHelper.aspx) using TestHelper and NUnit to test routes.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/), its a blog by the renowned Steve Sanderson. It covers unit tests and intregration tests, and uses the MvcIntegrationTestFramework

Another way is to see this [post from Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx)